# Windows tap takes long to respond

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2, win-universal-app, winjs

I've created an Ionic 2 app. Now I have my buttons set up like this:

`<button class="my-button" (tap)="doSomething()" tappable></button>`

Now the `tappable` should remove the 300ms delay on a tap.

The ionic docs aren't too great on gestures but [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#gestures)'s a demo of how tap should work

The problem I encounter is that, when I build for windows, the buttons still are very slow to respond to a tap event. Why is this? On iOS and Android, they're both very quick.

I thought it might have to do with loading pages after clicking a button but this isn't the case since normal buttons on a page

```
$ cordova platform version windows
 Installed platforms:
  android 5.0.0
  ios 4.3.1
  windows 4.4.3
```

Please note that using `(click)` instead of `(tap)` doesn't solve the issue.

**Edit 1**: In the emulator this issue does not occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is an `ionic` specific issue.

After updating my ionic versions, creating a new project and copying all my pages and logic from my previous project to the new, the taps, clicks and animations are now really fast.

Commands I used:

- `npm uninstall -g ionic cordova`
- `npm install -g ionic cordova`
- (copy src, assets, config.xml, index.html)
- `ionic cordova run windows --prod --release --arch="arm"`

Previous ionic versions:

```
$ ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.7
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Not installed
```

New ionic version:

```
$ ionic info

cli packages: (C:\Users\ivaro18(no-not-serious)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.9.1\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 windows 5.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 25.2.2
    Node              : v6.9.1
    npm               : 3.10.8
    OS                : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not using ionic, but found that (tap) doesn't work well on touch screens.
This helped me:

> touch-action is also often used to completely disable the delay of
>   click events caused by support for the double-tap to zoom gesture.

```
button{
    touch-action: manipulation;
}
```

Comment: Good answer for people not using Ionic. Ionic has this as a default setting for all buttons, links etc